# problem with multi statement table valued function, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function

I having problems with this function, seems like `@idUsuario` and `@passCorrecto` aren't getting any value, so, when I use this variables in the where clause I'm not getting any result data.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[login](@usuario varchar(20), @password varchar(20))

RETURNS @info TABLE (nombre varchar(70) not null, tipo varchar(30) not null)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @idUsuario int = dbo.usuarioExiste(@usuario)
    DECLARE @passCorrecto bit = dbo.passwordCorrecto(@idUsuario, @password) 

    INSERT @info
        SELECT
            usuarios.nombreUsuario, tiposUsuarios.tipoUsuario
        FROM 
            usuarios
        LEFT JOIN
            tiposUsuarios
        ON
            usuarios.idTipoUsuario = tiposUsuarios.idTipoUsuario
        WHERE
            usuarios.idUsuario = @idUsuario and              
            usuarios.estatus = 'ACTIVO' and
            @passCorrecto = 1
    RETURN 

END
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Here are the function used above:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[usuarioExiste]
(
    @usuario varchar(20)
)
RETURNS integer
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @idUsuario integer

    SELECT
        @idUsuario = idUsuario
    FROM
        usuarios
    WHERE
        usuario = @usuario

    if @idUsuario is null begin
        set @idUsuario = 0
    end

    RETURN @idUsuario

END


ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[passwordCorrecto]
(
    @usuario varchar(20),
    @password varchar(20)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @esCorrecto bit

    SELECT
        @esCorrecto = case when password = @password then 1 else 0 end
    FROM
        usuarios
    WHERE 
        usuario = @usuario

    RETURN @esCorrecto

END
```

**EDIT 2**

As suggested by Beth, I created new functions that returns the values that I need like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[usuarioExisteTest]
(
    @usuario varchar(20)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    declare @idUsuario int;
    set @idUsuario = 1;

    return (@idUsuario);

END;
```

By doing this I'm getting the data I need, am I setting the values to return the wrong way in the original functions?

```
DECLARE @idUsuario integer

        SELECT
            @idUsuario = idUsuario
        FROM
            usuarios
        WHERE
            usuario = @usuario
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  You can't declare and set variables on the same line in 2005 or earlier.

Comment: @LittleBobby - That would raise a syntax error though. I suspect the issue must be in the definition or call of `dbo.usuarioExiste(@usuario)`

Comment: @Martin Smith -- I thought of that too, after I posted it, but figured it couldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: @bobby I'm using sql server 2008. @Martin ´usuarioExiste(@usuario)´ works fine when I call it like this ´SELECT dbo.usuarioExiste('htorres')´

Comment: What are the values of @idUsuario and @passCorrecto immediately after declaration?

Comment: Don't forget to hash and salt those usuario passwords.

Comment: @Joe I'm not sure, @idUsuario and @passCorrecto should get '1' (one) as value, @idUsuario as int and @passCorrecto as bit. @Denis I won't, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, seem like using select `@var = some_value` doesn't work well. [See this:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187330.aspx)

```
A SELECT statement that contains a variable assignment cannot be used to also perform typical result set retrieval operations.
```

These are the fixed functions:
usuarioExiste

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[usuarioExiste]
(
    @usuario varchar(20)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    declare @idUsuario int = 0;

    set @idUsuario = (
        select
            idUsuario
        from
            usuarios
        where
            usuario = @usuario);

    if @idUsuario is null begin
        set @idUsuario = 0;
    end;

    return (@idUsuario);

END;
```

passwordCorrecto

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[passwordCorrecto]
(
    @idUsuario int,
    @password varchar(20)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN

    declare @esCorrecto bit = 'false';

    set @esCorrecto = (
        select
            case when password = @password then 'true' else 'false' end
        from
            usuarios
        where 
            usuarios.idUsuario = @idUsuario);

    return (@esCorrecto);

END;
```

and login

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[login](@usuario varchar(20), @password varchar(20))

RETURNS @info TABLE (nombre varchar(70) not null, tipo varchar(30) not null)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @idUsuario int = dbo.usuarioExistetest(@usuario);

    DECLARE @passCorrecto bit = dbo.passwordCorrectotest(@idUsuario, @password);

    INSERT @info
        SELECT
            usuarios.nombreUsuario, tiposUsuarios.tipoUsuario
        FROM 
            usuarios
        LEFT JOIN
            tiposUsuarios
        ON
            usuarios.idTipoUsuario = tiposUsuarios.idTipoUsuario
        WHERE
            usuarios.idUsuario = @idUsuario and
            usuarios.estatus = 'ACTIVO' and
            @passCorrecto = 'true';
    RETURN 

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know SQL Server 2008 supports the combined DECLARE/assign, but have you tried separating them?

```
DECLARE @idUsuario int
SET idUsuario = dbo.usuarioExiste(@usuario)
DECLARE @passCorrecto bit 
SET passCorrecto = dbo.passwordCorrecto(@idUsuario, @password)
```

[From BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx)

> Assigns a value to the variable
>   in-line. The value can be a constant
>   or an expression, but it must either
>   match the variable declaration type or
>   be implicitly convertible to that
>   type.

Of course, a udf *is* an expression, but is it possible there is some anomaly when used in DECLARE (like when you use a udf in CHECK constraint: it's not reliable). Or DECLARE ins a udf for some reason.

Please humour me. Try it.

Also, you have no "failsafe" inside `dbo.passwordCorrecto` which means it could return NULL which will always evaluate to false in the outer udf.

Comment: Hi, I already tryed separated statements with the same result... also, could you explain to me how failsafe works? thanks gbn

Answer (score 0):

try printing the values of the variables after you declare them.  If they aren't set correctly, try calling the functions in a new query window instead of within [dbo].[login].  That should help identify the problem.

Comment: printing is not allowed in funtions beth, well, it shows me an error when I put something like PRINT @idUsuario

Comment: OK, try creating two other functions that only declare and return your variable values.

Comment: then that's not the problem.  Try executing the Select outside the function declaration to determine if the problem is with the select or not.